# Kontakt player not available as a Pro Tools 11 plugin

Tags: pro-tools, instruments, kontakt, native

I have just installed the komplete elements program onto my mac, and for some reason the Kontakt player is not available as an instrument plugin in pro tools. I am running Pro Tools 11 on Mac OS X Mavericks, and I updated everything in the Komplete Elements bundle through Native Instruments. Reaktor is available as a plugin. I can see "Kontakt 5.dpm" in the Pro Tools plugin folder, but I don't know how to access it from within the program. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: have contacted native instruments already? or did you check there forum? this seems a bit off topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a specific product and not at all about sound design.

Answer (score 2):

Pro Tools 11 does not use .dpm plugins.
It only uses 64bit AAX plugins. If you log into native instruments service center, it will show you all available updates for your registered software. This includes updates to Kontakt 5 that provide the necessary 64bit AAX plugin format for use with Pro Tools 11.

The NI Service Center Updater is not smart enough to look for whether or not you have AAX plugins, and NI support is not smart enough to realize this, so they keep repeating the worthless mantra "make sure you update to the latest version with Service Center." If you used an installer that did not have a checkbox specifically for AAX, for instance Kontakt 5.0, and have only run updates since then, they were not installed and never will be no matter how many times you update with SC. It will update all your applications to the newest versions- Kontakt, Reaktor, etc.- but will not install AAX. You have to login into the site and download the newest versions of each individual application manually. These installers will now have checkboxes for AAX.